# Flutter error when build appbundle (Script '/Users/****/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, gradle, release, android-app-bundle

My app is running very well in debug mode. Now I am trying to build an appbundle for release, but have error.

Oops; flutter has exited unexpectedly: "Invalid argument(s): Cannot find executable for /Users/*****/Developer/flutter/bin/cache/artifacts/engine/android-arm64-release/darwin-x64/gen_snapshot.".
A crash report has been written to /Users/*****/AndroidStudioProjects/*********/flutter_04.log.
This crash may already be reported. Check GitHub for similar crashes.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues?q=is%3Aissue+Invalid+argument%28s%29%3A+Cannot+find+executable+for+%2FUsers%2F*****%2FDeveloper%2Fflutter%2Fbin%2Fcache%2Fartifacts%2Fengine%2Fandroid-arm64-release%2Fdarwin-x64%2Fgen_snapshot.

To report your crash to the Flutter team, first read the guide to filing a bug.
https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/bug-reports

Create a new GitHub issue by pasting this link into your browser and completing the issue template. Thank you!
https://git.io/JO1nF

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/****/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 991
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command '/Users/*****/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 58s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        58.8s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1

I don't nkow what to do. Thanks for those who can suggest me something.

Comment: Have you used 'Internet Permission' in android?

Comment: Yes I used it. With my research on internet, I think the problem is gen_snapshot, I am looking how to solve that. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to build appbundle by running in the terminal

```
flutter upgrade -f
flutter channel master
flutter upgrade
```

But I am facing another problem: when I run in release mode, it stuck at this
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...

Comment: try to connect and use a real device not a simulator to install and run your release apk.@Vincent

Comment: The problem is solve. The problem was caused by the interstitial ads. I just delete all interstitial ads and it work.